# Using SDF instead of URDF with Robot State Publisher

Tags: ros, urdf, sdf, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With **URDF** models, you can use `robot_state_publisher` to have the joints published in `tf`. Since this needs the `<robot>` tag, it does not work with **SDF** models. If you try to `roslaunch` for a SDF it would say

```
Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
```

Everything else works fine in gazebo but the state publisher dies

Is there any way I can use **robot state publisher** with SDF? Maybe include URDF into the SDF? Or specify the `<robot>` tag in it somehow?

---

**TL;DR:**

I have found many other questions related to this question but none had a positive answer and most of them are more than 5 years old. However,

- [This answer](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/62/sdf-vs-urdf-what-should-one-use/) suggests that you can do anything with SDF that is possible in URDF.
- [This question](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/4192/problem-with-sdf-files-or-robot_description-parameter/) has an answer suggesting an alternative by having both URDF and SDF but it's an ugly solution
- There's this [old unanswered question](https://answers.ros.org/question/204803/robot_state_publisher-with-sdf-files/) as well

I want to created a 6 wheeled robot model with two wheels having **shock absorbers** (prismatic joints with damping and spring actions). To my understanding, [this cannot be done using URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint#line-67)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357026/using-sdf-instead-of-urdf-with-robot-state-publisher/) by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2020-07-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @teshansj,

The main question here is why you want to use the native Gazebo description format with ROS utilities. Looking at the `robot_state_publisher` implementation you can see that it uses a KDL tree to parse only URDFs, that are the standard robot description format used in ROS, since RST is a ROS application you cannot expect it can parse other than the standard formats.

The second question is if there is a real need for using a SDF since ROS already support a direct translation between: Xacro -> URDF -> SDF to be able to spawn models on Gazebo worlds. So from here we reach this point in your question:

*I want to created a 6 wheeled robot model with two wheels having shock absorbers (prismatic joints with damping and spring actions). To my understanding, this cannot be done using URDF*

An that is actually not true, since you can create 4 normal wheels and another 2 with a shock absorber joint, I know this because I was able to implement that in a Gazebo Car model. The most important thing here is that while you cannot use URDF things in SDF files, you can use SDF tags in URDF files. And that is done with the  tag.

So if you really want to generate a shock absrober joint you can use in a URDF the  tag with the `reference` name as your joint name and provide the proper [dynamic](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.7&elem=joint#axis_dynamics) parameters.

This will look like:

For the joint

```
<joint name="shock" type="prismatic">
  <parent link=parent"/>
  <child link="child"/>
  <origin xyz="x y z" rpy="r p y" />
  <axis xyz="x y z"/>
  <limit lower="low" upper="upp" effort="eff" velocity="vel"/>
  <dynamics damping="damp" friction="fric"/>
</joint>
```

and for the SDF

```
<gazebo reference="shock">
  <implicitSpringDamper>true</implicitSpringDamper>
  <springStiffness>[stiffness]</springStiffness>
  <springReference>[reference]</springReference>
</gazebo>
```

That should fill the SDF  tag to generate a good shock absorber joint.

With that you willl have your URDF and no problems when using RSP. Apart from that I recommend you [Xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) instead of URDF.

Hope it helps.

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on 2020-07-14**:
After posting this question I actually got it to work using gazebo tags. I wasn't aware of the `<gazebo>` tag at the time of posting the question. Anyway I'm going to let the question be as it is since your answer might help others as well.

**Comment by [LR](https://answers.ros.org/users/60755/lr/) on 2020-10-10**:
if I want to use the gearbox joint of sdf file,but there is not the gearbox joint in urdf file,and what I should do by using  tag?

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-10-12**:
@LR, This a different question from the original post, hence, following community rules you may want to write your question in a different post. However, since this I think has a fast solution you can try with the `<gazebo>` tag like:

```
<gazebo>
  <joint name="joint_gearbox" type="gearbox">
    <parent>parent_link</parent>
    <child>child_link</child>
    <gearbox_reference_body>${name}_base_link</gearbox_reference_body>
    <gearbox_ratio>1</gearbox_ratio>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
    </axis>

    <axis2>
      <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
    </axis2>
  </joint>
</gazebo>
```

**Comment by [LR](https://answers.ros.org/users/60755/lr/) on 2020-10-12**:
what is the reference frame of the  in  and ?I have set the revolute joint between parent_link/child_link and ${name}_base_link,so the reference frame of  is parent_link/child_link frame?and thanks for you advices.

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-10-12**:
@LR You can check everything about this is the SDF format specification [here](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.7&elem=joint). But to answer your question, extracted from the manual:

1. `axis`: *Parameters related to the axis of rotation for revolute joints, the axis of translation for prismatic joints.*
2. `axis2`: *Parameters related to the second axis of rotation for revolute2 joints and universal joints.*

Basically `axis` is the input axis (relative to child) and `axis2` is output axis (relative to child). You can also check the `joint_demo` from gazebo [here](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo_models/blob/d3fce8e73461d9c65324762a04c4019a23132210/demo_joint_types/model.sdf) to know more about this.